# neovis.js is not displaying nodes at all

Tags: neo4j, localhost, neovis

I was trying to visualize my Neo4j data hosted on localhost Neo4j desktop and auradb. But I tried the code below and it just shows me empty white space where nodes should be displayed.
I check all my db instances are running and cannot find reason neovis cannot fetch any data from db. Can you help me what i should do to get it right? i tried several other things like neo4j://dbId.databases.neo4j.io and bolt://dbId.databases.neo4j.io but all of them did not work:(

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Neovis.js Simple Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            font: 16pt arial;
        }

        #viz {
            width: 900px;
            height: 700px;
            border: 1px solid lightgray;
            font: 22pt arial;
        }

    </style>

    <!-- import from CDN -->
    
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/neovis.js@2.0.2/dist/neovis-without-dependencies.js"></script>

    <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        // define config car
        // instantiate nodevis object
        // draw
        var viz;

        function draw() {
            var config = {
                container_id: "viz",
                serverUrl: "bolt://127.0.0.1:7687",
                serverUser: "cee",
                serverPassword: "niax1729@",
                //encrypted: "ENCRYPTION_ON",
                //trust: "TRUST_SYSTEM_CA_SIGNED_CERTIFICATES",
                /*neo4j: {
                    serverUrl: "neo4j+s://dbId.databases.neo4j.io",
                    serverUser: "neo4j",
                    serverPassword: "passwd",
                    driverConfig: { 
                    encrypted: "ENCRYPTION_ON",
                    trust: "TRUST_SYSTEM_CA_SIGNED_CERTIFICATES"
                    }
                }, */
                labels: {
                    /* Character: {
                        label: "name",
                        value: "pagerank",
                        group: "community"
                    } */
                },
                relationships: {
                    /* INTERACTS: {
                        value: "weight"
                    } */
                },
                initialCypher: "MATCH p=(n:Review)-[r:Inter]-(m:Review) RETURN p"
            };

            viz = new NeoVis.default(config);
            viz.render();
            console.log(viz);

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="draw()">
<div id="viz"></div>


Cypher query: <textarea rows="4" cols=50 id="cypher"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="reload">
<input type="submit" value="Stabilize" id="stabilize">


</body>

<script>
    $("#reload").click(function () {

        var cypher = $("#cypher").val();

        if (cypher.length > 3) {
            viz.renderWithCypher(cypher);
        } else {
            console.log("reload");
            viz.reload();

        }

    });

    $("#stabilize").click(function () {
        viz.stabilize();
    })

</script>
</html>
```